# Documenting function params when wrapping a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, wrapper, type-hinting

I've written some code to wrap shutil.copy file like so (this is a largely simplified example):

```
from functools import wraps
from shutil import copyfile


def my_wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@my_wrapper
def mycopyfile(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrap :func:`shutil.copyfile`"""
    return copyfile(*args, **kwargs)
```

In PyCharm, if I type `mycopyfile.` it suggests *args, and **kwargs as the params. How can I make it so PyCharm, and other IDE's suggest the params of shutil.copyfile?

In addition, the quick docs in PyCharm use the documents for mycopyfile, rather than the docs shutil.copy file, even though mycopyfile.**doc** returns the docs correctly (as deteremined by the @wraps decorator)

Comment: It's not obvious how static analysis could suggest the params of `shutil.copyfile` in this case.

Comment: At Python level you can fake it by doing: `wrapper.__signature__ = signature(copyfile)`. Where signature is from inspect import signature`.